INDIRECT function for range of rows = cell, #ref error
So in Excel I'm trying to reference a rage of rows (from another sheet) = C34,
The formula is:

=FILTER(CHOOSE({1},INDIRECT(C4&"!C:C")),W!F:F=C34)

the problem is in W!F:F=C34 part.
C4: holds sheet names (dropdown list), in this case "W".
I tried:


=FILTER(CHOOSE({1},INDIRECT(C4&"!C:C")),INDIRECT(C4&"!F:F=C34")
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1},INDIRECT(C4&"!C:C")),INDIRECT(C4&"!F:F"&"="&C34)


I got different errors, all didnt work.

Why use CHOOSE with just one option? =FILTER(INDIRECT(C4&"!C:C"),INDIRECT(C4&"!F:F")=C34) untested.

@P.b INDIRECT(C4&"!F:F")=C34), is the right formula, set it as an answer. Thank you

=FILTER(INDIRECT(C4&"!C:C"),INDIRECT(C4&"!F:F")=C34)


Shouldn't @P.b. submit the answer?

@bugdrown - no. Despite the advisory not to answer questions in comments, P.b did just that. There are several discussions on Meta that suggest that someone other than the poster of the comment can then absolutely post that as an answer and should not be faulted for doing so.

I posted it as a comment, as I was unsure it would be the right syntax without testing. That and me not responding in time to the suggestion to post as an answer, leaves it open to close the post as answered by Wert trew

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
